# Store several variables into single file

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hue

I have several logs and do some filtering on them.
A a result I have several variables, every of them is count of some statistic. And I save them in different files like this:

```
STORE (FOREACH (GROUP A ALL) GENERATE COUNT(A)) INTO '$save_dir/A_result';
STORE (FOREACH (GROUP B ALL) GENERATE COUNT(B)) INTO '$save_dir/B_result';
STORE (FOREACH (GROUP C ALL) GENERATE COUNT(C)) INTO '$save_dir/C_result';
```

Result of any of this lines - just one number.
How to join or concat/union them into one variable to store into a single file instead of three different?

I tried this approach:

```
B_count = FOREACH (GROUP B ALL) GENERATE COUNT(B) as b1;
result_record = FOREACH (GROUP A all) GENERATE
                'my_results' AS name,
                COUNT(A) as a1,
                B_count.b1 as b1;
STORE result_record INTO '$save_dir/total';
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Create relations to store the individual counts,union them all into another relation and store them to a single file

```
A_count = (FOREACH (GROUP A ALL) GENERATE COUNT(A));
B_count = (FOREACH (GROUP B ALL) GENERATE COUNT(B));
C_count = (FOREACH (GROUP C ALL) GENERATE COUNT(C));

D = UNION A_count,B_count,C_count;

STORE D INTO '$save_dir/total'
```

Comment: Thank you for response! Good idea but still not solve the problem - your solution generates 3 different files in one directory :) I made some improvement, but still have some problems (take a look please)

Answer (score 0):

Using [@VK_217](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64592442/4960953) idea I made this one:

```
A_count = FOREACH (GROUP A ALL) GENERATE COUNT(A);
B_count = FOREACH (GROUP B ALL) GENERATE COUNT(B);
C_count = FOREACH (GROUP C ALL) GENERATE COUNT(C);

D = UNION A_count,B_count,C_count;

Result = GROUP D BY 1; 
Result = FOREACH Result GENERATE FLATTEN(Result);
STORE Result INTO '$save_dir/total';
```

This generates one file consists of 3 records in column. This is OK.
But I still have several problems:

- PIG can write results in different order. So sometime it A_count/B_count/C_count but sometimes - C_count/A_count/B_count etc. So it make result useless...
- If any of counters equals to zero, PIG doesn't write 0. Just skip this line.
- Have no idea how to add names of counters to the result file.